# CakePHP search entities where association's field is equal to string

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Okay... this is a bit hard to explain. I want to search my table for `Projects` where

`['Projects.name LIKE' => "%$searchQuery%"]`

This works fine. But the thing is that `Projects` has an belongsTo association to `Customers` and I want to see if the search query also fits the two fields of `Customers`, `Customers.firstName` and `Customers.lastName`. If it does it has to include the project to the list.

So to sum it up.

I want to search a list of projects (This list includes the project name, the customers first and last names). The search query should search the Projects and see if the name matches. I also want it to check if the search query matches the Customers first and last names, and if it does it should include the Projects which belongsTo that Customer.

Hope you can understand my question.

Here is my code right now (ProjectsController):

```
public function search()
{
    $searchQuery = isset($this->request->query['q']) ? $this->request->query['q'] : "";
    $searchQuery = "dfd";
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Customers']
    ];

    $projectsFiltered = $this->Projects->find('all')->where(['Projects.archived' => 0, 'Projects.name LIKE' => "%$searchQuery%"]);
    $projects = $this->paginate($projectsFiltered);

    $this->set(compact('projects'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['projects']);
    $this->set('query', $searchQuery);
}
```

Comment: And you're struggling with _what programming problem exactly_? Currently there is no question in your question, just a task.

Answer (score 1):

seems you just don't know how to do a simple OR

```
$projectsFiltered = $this->Projects->find('all')
    ->where([
        'Projects.archived' => 0, 
        'OR' => [
            'Projects.name LIKE' => "%$searchQuery%",
            'Customers.firstName LIKE' => "%$searchQuery%",
            'Customers.lastNameLIKE' => "%$searchQuery%"
         ]
    ])
    ->contain(['Customers', 'Customers.Projects']);
```

Comment: Thank you, now it works. However if i search for the full name with the first and last name it shows no results and I can see why. How would you do it so this will show all the projects that belongs to the customer?

Comment: if you want to show the customer's projects just include them in the `contain()` method (see my edit). Don't know what you intend when you say 'if i search for the full name'...

Comment: So I don't know if you understood what i meant to do, but it didn't work. I found another solution by googling a bit. `'concat_ws(\' \',Customers.firstName,Customers.lastName) LIKE' => "%$searchQuery%"` Seems to be working for me. Could you update the answer with this, so I can accept it. ;)

Comment: Try https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search instead. It is a much nicer and less redundant way of implementing what you want.